# Do I need to drop index on temp table?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Fairly simple question, but I don't see it anywhere else on SO:

Do indexes (indices?) on a temporary table get automatically deleted with the temporary table?

I'd imagine they do but I don't really know how to check to make sure.

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they get dropped along with the table. It is not possible for an index to exist independently of its table.

In terms of checking this for yourself you could do

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID), * FROM tempdb.sys.indexes
```

before and after running your DROP temp table.